# Check that a point is at the end of a line using Data Reviewer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, data-reviewer

I am attempting to verify that points are at the ends of lines using Data Reviewer in Arcgis 10.8. So far the closest thing I have found is using Valency, but Valency only checks lines connectivity to points, not the other way around. Basically I need a way to flag this point since it is not at the end of the lines feature class. I know this is possible using Topology, but would like to do this using Data Reviewer.

[image: Example]

Comment: Extract line ends and select existing points by them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the data reviewer but a very simple way of identifying points that are not at the end or on any line is to use the [select by location tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) and simply select all points that intersect the line dataset and ensure invert selection is ticked on.

Comment: Yeah I know that would work, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish this within Data Reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by doing the following steps:

1. Creating a Geometry on Geometry check.
2. Setting the Feature Class 1 as the point
3. Setting the Feature Class 2 as the line
4. Set the Spatial Relation Check type to "Touches" with the "Not" box checked

Think of the end vertices of the line as the outer part of its boundary.  This is why "Touches" works as opposed to "Intersect."